# Wit.ai: How to send a message when confidence below a certain level?

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger, wit.ai

I'm playing around with the Wit.ai Facebook Messenger Example (https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit/blob/master/examples/messenger.js)

Is there a way to send a preset response when the user's message is not understood. I was thinking along the lines of some way of stopping the Wit conversation when the confidence is below a certain threshold.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wit API directly and skip the ui all together if you want more fine control.

```
function getIntent(message) {
  var serviceResult = {};
  var url = 'https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20161006&q='+message;
  var options = {
    uri: url,
    qs: {},
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {},
    auth: {'bearer': process.env.WIT_TOKEN},
    json: true
  };
  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if(!error) {
      serviceResult.result = "success";
      // Check for entities
      if(body.entities.contact) {
        serviceResult.entity = body.entities.contact[0].value;
        serviceResult.entityConfidence = body.entities.contact[0].confidence;
      }
      // Check for intent
      if(body.entities.intent) {
        serviceResult.intent = body.entities.intent[0].value;
        serviceResult.intentConfidence = body.entities.intent[0].confidence;
      }
    }
    else {
      serviceResult.result = "fail";
    }
  });
}
```

Your bot can decide what it wants to do based on the confidence value.